# How do I generate bitcoin addresses with computer code?

Tags: blockchain, payment, bitcoin, wallet

I have a website, and I need each user of the site to have their own unique bitcoin address. Any funds sent to these addresses I need to be automatically transferred to a master wallet for me.

Any ideas on how I can set this up easily? The first stage is to generate bitcoin wallet addresses with code. I have no idea how to do this. The second question is then how do I access those funds and withdraw the money.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bitcoin Core Api `getaccountaddress` with the `account` parameter as the user Unique ID from your Database. It will generate addresses that belongs to specific user but with a single Private Key that you own.

You can spend the funds with just normal transaction on Bitcoin Core Wallet.